# Accordion in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a simple accordion to my page, so I browsed w3schools and found the tutorial. But in it's javascript code there is a for loop that I can't understand what is does. can anyone explain it?
here is the code:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the link to actual w3schools page:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Comment: all this loop does is it create a click listener on the accordion buttons and whenever any of the accordion button is clicked add the active class to button. get the sibling element that contains the content of the accordion and change its display property to block and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This for loop is used to uniquely identify the onlick operation for each accordion element.

This is used to get all the elements from the page with class as accordion

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
```

As there are multiple elements with the name accordion so now you start iterating over each element of the of the `acc` variable

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
```

Now for each element in the `acc` array you define a `onclick` operation and set the toggle element for it.
    acc[i].onclick = function(){

Change the toggle class to active for the selected accordion and toggle the panel to block/none on each click of the accordion.

```
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps..:)

Comment: Happy to help always..:)

Answer (score 0):

Have added few more comments for ease of understanding

```
// get all the elements which have same class name.
// it will return a html collection.
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

// now looping through the collection & adding event to each of the element.
// click is a event name
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    // adding onclick event to each of the element
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        // toggle will remove a class if it there & if not there it will add the class
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        // each of the element have a sibling p element.
        // depending on the scenario it is showing and hiding the p element
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            // will hide the p element
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            // will show p element
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there have used 3 examples.so they put it in for loop.In normal way, single accordian

```
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
 acc.onclick = function(){
    /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
    to highlight the button that controls the panel */
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
        panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        panel.style.display = "block";
    }
    }
```

or (Simple Jquery method)

```
$('.accordian').on('click', function(){
  this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
        panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        panel.style.display = "block";
    }

});
```

They have 3 `accordian` classes..so they are saved as array in this line.Then get the every element in the for loop

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
```